# Displaying huge amount of data (in json object) in Kendo UI tree view. Give stack overflow error with huge records

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, kendo-ui, stack

I need to display all the records in a kendo view tree view at one go. Means at load of tree, I want all the nodes of my hierarchical data to be displayed. When data is less, I am getting no issue. But when my data is high, I am getting stack overflow error at line number:3, say.

When I debug the visual studio code, I get : "0x800a001c - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Out of stack space"

Actually what is happening, when a child node is displayed, kendo checks for the parent node. So if we have multiple child nodes, recursive calls are happening to get the parent node. With huge data, recursive calls are huge. Hence getting stack overflow error. Can anyone here help me out what I should change in my code.

I am using MVC for this. And 'treeData' contains json data.
The data is coming from the service in hierarchical format.

```
  _intializeStudentTree: function () {
        var abc = this;
        var treeData = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "controller1/method1",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                },
                parameterMap: function (options) {
                    options['StudentID'] = abc.options.list.StudentId;
                    options['StudentDetails'] = abc.options.list.StudentDetails;
                    return JSON.stringify(options);
                }
            },
            schema: {
                model: {
                    children: "ChildRecords"
                }
            }
        });

        abc.subscriptionListTree = abc.element.find('.tree-view').kendoTreeView({
            template: kendo.template($("#temp-treeview").html()),
            animation: {
                expand:false
            },
            dataSource: treeData,
            dataTextField: ["StudentLevel"],
            loadOnDemand: false,
            dataBound: function () {
                thiz.subscriptionListTree.expand(".k-item");
            }
        }).data('kendoTreeView');
    },
```

Comment: it would be of great help if any one can figure it out what can be done to fix this.

Comment: Can you please try with the load on demand data?

Comment: hi jayesh. thanks. But I want my whole tree with all the nodes expanded..when the tree loads initially.

Comment: jayesh..its giving the same error with the load on demand data..

Comment: Which version of KendoUI are you using?

Comment: I am using kendo version: 2014.1.318